# Python, Checking a dictionary for values using .itervalues() returns different results on comparison

Tags: python, dictionary

Why are the Comparison #1 and Comparison #2 have different evaluation results?

```
list = [{'objItem':{'key':'exists', 'a':'aaa', 'b':'bbb', 'c':'ccc', 'd':'ddd'}}]
valA = "aaa"
valB = "bbb"
valC = "ccc"


#Comaprisson 1
if valC in list[0]['objItem'].itervalues() and valA in list[0]['objItem'].itervalues() and valB in list[0]['objItem'].itervalues():
    print "True #1"
else:
    print "False #1"

#Comparisson 2
values = list[0]['objItem'].itervalues()
if valC in values and valA in values and valB in values:
    print "True #2"
else:
    print "False #2"
```

Results in:

```
$python main.py
True #1
False #2
```

Thank you

Comment: as an aside, you should never name a list, `list`

Comment: itervalues() returns a iterator.First convert iterator list[0]['objItem'].itervalues() into list & then compare it will return True.

Comment: Use values = list[0]['objItem'].values() instead of values = list[0]['objItem'].itervalues() ,it will give you a list. This is alternative answer you try first one earlier comment or use in current comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Itervalues (as seen on [python-reference](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/itervalues.html)) gives an iterator and not the list of values of a map. 
The right way to get the collection of values would be through values() if using python 3. [ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)
For python 2, 
the correct way would be to take it as list(list[0]['objItem'].itervalues()) as per this example.

As to why the two are are returning different results:
As user 0TTT0 mentioned earlier , 
An iterator exhausts its values when you are using the values method.
But if you tried

> valC in list[0]['objItem'].itervalues()

again after your code snippet, it would return true.
This is because list[0]['objItem'].itervalues() returns a new iterator object everytime. But values, on the other hand, has a stored iterator object.
So: valC in values would consume "ccc" in the values operator but valC in list[0]['objItem'].itervalues() gets to consume a new iterators "ccc" everytime!

On a side note: 
I would advise usage against list as a variable.
1. Because naming a variable the same as the object type is bad practice.
2. You can name it something more descriptive and plural

Answer (score 2):

As `itervalues()` returns an iterator, during comparisons it is going to run through the iterator until it finds the value or extinguishes the iterator. In your case, you checked for `valC` which is the last value available in the iterator, so when it goes to check for the next value in the comparison, `valB`, there is nothing left to check.  Instead, if you had written `if valA in values and valB in values and valC in values:` a true value would have been returned.

Comment: Actually, no: valC in values returns false. It appears that membership is false after the iterator has been assigned to a variable. But membership seems to be true if you directly check for membership before the iterator returned by itervalues() has been assigned to a variable.

Comment: umm did you run the code?  `print(valC in values)` returns True

Comment: Ran and checked on tutorialspoint. Not sure what the difference is over here. Perhaps a difference in python version. OP's question seems to be in python 2.something.

Comment: yeah im running 3, which uses `iter(...)` instead of `.itervalues`.. but they should give the same results

Comment: I believe v2.7.13 atleast gives a different result. Please try here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php

Comment: ran his exact code on that site and input `print valC in values` below the definition of `values` and it returns True

Comment: can you try it after the whole block of code instead? I got true if I ran print valC in values after declaration as well

Comment: after the whole block it is going to return `False` because the iterator has already been extinguished..  that's what i wrote about in the answer.....

Comment: my bad- agreed!